# Sort PHP array with children under parents

Tags: php

In this example I have an array of elements.

```
$array = ["Element A", "Element B", "Element C", "Element D", "Element E"]
```

After making a database call (I already figured this part out...), it is determined that "B" and "D" are children of element E. Additionally, "A" is a child of "C".

For demonstration purposes, `parent($a)` would return `"c"` while `parent($e)` would return `NULL`.

How can I reorder the array so that all children elements are directly below their parent elements?

The correct solution is something like these, where children are directly after parents:

```
["E", "B", "D", "C", "A"]
["E", "D", "B", "C", "A"]
["C", "A", "E", "B", "D"]
["C", "A", "E", "D", "B"]
```

Comment: Where do you want the array sorted? Via SQL (your database call) or in Php? Right now, you'd have to loop over the elements in `$array` and call `parent($array[$i])` if using a `for` loop, figure out how to change their order or push to a new sorted array.

Comment: What do you want your result to look like?  Should it be `['C', 'A', 'E', 'B', 'D']`?  Something else?  Do you want a multidimensional array?  What does "below" mean?

Comment: Might help to show the result of your DB call. I.e., how "it is determined" which elements are children of which.

Comment: Need more details: database structure, example data, current solution.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to represent multiple tree structures using the same sorted array. I do not think it is a good idea to begin with.

Comment: @VCNinc: How do you know that's what the OP is asking for?  Plus, you show multiple examples and I'm sure the OP only wants *one* of those.  Don't edit the question unless you know *exactly* what the OP wants.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I simply included what I know to be all of the valid answers to the question.

Comment: @VCNinc: But you just assumed it.  Don't edit the question solely based on assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following general structure can outline how to order your issue.

```
if(CHILD) {
    if(PARENT EXISTS) {
        DELETE THIS ELEMENT
        INSERT AT LOCATION
    } else {
        DELETE THIS ELEMENT
        ADD PARENT
        RE-ADD THIS ELEMENT
    }
}
```

No specifics, just an outline...

Comment: This outline allowed me to create the actual code, thanks! (accepted)